# Passing an array of Structures from C++(COM) to C#

Tags: c#, c++, com, interop

I am trying to pass an Array of Structures from C++(COM) to C#

```
        //C++ definition
        //MyStruct being a COM Visible Structure 
        HRESULT GetArrofStruct([in,out] LONG* count, [out,size_is(,*pnCnt)] MyStruct** ppArr);

        //C# definition
        void GetArrofStruct(ref int Count,out IntPtr outPtr);

        //I use the Function Something like this in C#

        IntPtr buffer = IntPtr.Zero;

        int Count;

        GetArrofStruct(ref Count,out buffer);
        MyStruct[] arrayManaged = new MyStruct[Count];

        for (int i = 0, nElemOffs = (int)buffer; i < Count; i++)
        {
            ru[i] = (MyStruct)Marshal.PtrToStructure((IntPtr)nElemOffs, typeof(MyStruct));
            nElemOffs += Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(MyStruct));
        }
```

In the for loop, the first element gets marshalled correctly, for the second element onwards I get a AccessViolation.

In the C++ side the array seems to be properly filled.(Verified by debugging).

Comment: The C++ declaration is pretty nonsensical, what is `,*pnCnt`?  You cannot directly use it from C# anyway, no way to release the memory for the array.

Comment: Sorry, in the C++ declaration *pnCnt is actually *count. And I release the memory for the array by using Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(buffer) after the for loop in the C# code.

Comment: Did any answer solves your problem?

Answer (score 0):

You're using a pointer of pointer so you just need to increase the offset ( nElemOffs ) by the size of the pointer and not the size of the struct and dereference it.

### Explanation:

You are using `MyStruct**` on C++ side instead of `MyStruct*`, this means you need to dereference it before converting the pointer value into a struct.

Sample code:

```
int Count;
IntPtr pBuffer;

GetArrofStruct(ref Count,out pBuffer);
MyStruct[] arrayManaged = new MyStruct[Count];
unsafe
{
    Int32 buffer = (int)pBuffer;

    for (int i = 0; i < Count; i++)
    {
        // Read the memory position of the structure
        Int32 p = *((Int32*)buffer);
        arrayManaged[i] = (MyStruct)Marshal.PtrToStructure((IntPtr)p, typeof(MyStruct));

        buffer += 4; // increase by pointer size
    }  
}
```

#### Little side-note:

Ensure that your struct `MyStruct` has the same size on C# and C++ side, `[StructLayout(..)]` may help here.

Comment: Hi Karthik, i explained it a bit more.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you problem is in the (int)buffer cast. Operator + is different on int and on IntPtr. Look at the following:

```
   for (int i = 0; i < Count; i++)
   {
      IntPtr newPtr = buffer + i * sizeof(typeof(MyStruct));
      ru[i] = (MyStruct)Marshal.PtrToStructure(newPtr, typeof(MyStruct));
   }
```

I have not tested this, and I do not know if the content of your IntPtr is correct and correctly allocated, but this is how you should iterate through the array of structures.

As for marshaling problem, marshaling is defined by the IDL, so pls check your array definition. I am not sure ([out] arrays have always confused me), but it seems to me you have one dimension too many. Try the following (and please let me know if one is correct):

```
[out,size_is(pnCnt)] MyStruct** ppArr

[out,size_is(*pnCnt)] MyStruct* ppArr
```

Comment: I tried this, doing so doesnt raise the access violation exception. But only the first element of the array ru[0] seems to get marshalled correctly, for the rest I am getting garbage/junk values.